# How to access a constant or static on a subclass in php

Tags: php

I want a class-wide variable that can be accessed from a parent class but isn't instantiated.

```
class A {
  abstract public static $v;
  public function v(){
    echo static::$v;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  $v = 'Hello world';
}
```

An abstract static or const would be perfect but of course they don't exist, and while I could implement this through an abstract function abstract functions can't be static either.

One way to do it would be to simply say:

```
protected $var = 'const';
```

And then never change it again. However, I'd like some more guarantees, and this needlessly uses some memory for every instance of the class.

Is there anything that could make this possible (And practical)?

I'd like:

1. To declare it abstract so I can force subclasses to implement it
2. To declare it static or const so that it's a property of the class not the instance
3. To do it in a way that won't require jumping through a significant amount of hoops to implement or use

Comment: It's not a property, but couldn't you create a method in the parent class as final, and use that to return your const? It'd be inherited and unchangeable, and you'd just need to call the method to access it.

Comment: Ah no, I need it the other way around. (Sorry left out the extends in my example) I need A to use a static or const defined by it's child B

Comment: Well since you can't actually have abstract properties it's a moot point - it's just pseudocode

Comment: Yes but then I lose the ability to mandate it on extension like an abstract property (Unless I did something like trying to access it in the constructor, but that's still a runtime error rather than parsetime)

Comment: Yes but if you leave out the static and comment out the last line you can instantiate and do who knows what with B before any errors appear https://eval.in/512723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> abstract functions can't be static either.

They *shouldn't*, according to PHP5's "strict standards". [But they sure can.](https://3v4l.org/5hKJX)

PHP 7 is totally fine with it.
PHP 5 complains, but <s>that never stopped anyone</s> only if Strict Standards are on, which is not the case by default.

That said, is there anything wrong with using any old abstract, non-static method?
The following code works just fine.

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract function actualV();

    public function v()
    {
        echo $this->actualV();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function actualV()
    {
        return 'const';
    }
}
```

`(new B())->v();` will echo `const`.

And if a class does not implement `actualV`:

> Fatal error: Class C contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (A::actualV).

If you really really want to, you can slap a `static` in front of the `actualV` method declaration, change `$this->v()` to `static::v()` and disable strict standards (if they're on and you're using PHP 5) with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);`, and everything will still work just the same.

Comment: Hmm. The downside to not using a static is that you can't use it without an instance. Granted that's not something that's likely to happen in my specific case but still. Anyway, wouldn't your example be exactly the same as just marking v abstract in the first place?

Comment: Well `v()` echo's it, whereas `actualV()` just returns it. Apart from that, yes.